# Woocommerce makes purchaed products out-of-stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The strangest thing has happened while building a Woocommerce website; the stock management function of the plugin has stopped working properly out of the blue.

When I set a products "Manage Stock" and "Stock Quantity" and when that product is purchased, Woocommerce reduces its quantity level to -1 and makes it "Out-of-stock" even when there was more stock than was purchased!

Inimitably I suspected the custom checkout gateway I added but this behavior is the same even when I use the default Woocommerce checkouts and disable my custom checkout.

What could be causing this?

**Resolved!**

Ive found out what was causing the problem, its like these issues are always caused by 3rd party plugins. After deactivating all enabled plugins I noticed Woocomerce worded properly. So i was able to isolate the offending plugin. One called "One Click install" that came with the theme Im using.

Thank you all for your guidance.

Comment: I believe product inventory settings are default as follows:

Manage Stock = CHECKED,
Hold Stock (minutes) = 60,

Enable low stock notifications = CHECKED,
Enable out of stock notifications = CHECKED, 

Low Stock Threshold = 2, 
Out Of Stock Threshold = 0, 

Out Of Stock Visibility (hide) = UNCHECKED,
Stock Display Format = "Always show stock e.g 12 in stock"

Comment: what happen If you unset (inactivate your custom checkout gateway)? … Is this custom gateway a plugin? which one? Is it updated? … If you are facing an issue related to a plugin, best thing is to contact author's support threads, because here we can't help much more, with your question details…